# Git error when deploying app on push.drie.co

Tags: git, platform

I've deployed apps on drie-push before and it worked flawlessly. I added a new repo to git and my ssh keys seem to be fine but I am getting this error.

```
    git push drie master
    Permission denied (publickey).
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
```

Has anyone else seen this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like you are not using the correct credentials while communicating with the remote repo during the push.  Have you configured your password and certs?

Comment: each repository may have a different set of users/groups so it may be different from the other repositories. Check the repository settings on the server

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this to make it work.

```
git remote set-url drie storageroomz.app@push.drieapp.co:code.git
```

Answer (score 0):

double check the documentation here: https://drie.github.io/push-docs/getting-started.html#deploying
Common issues are naming your app the same as an existing app or not using the `${app_name}.app@push.drieapp.co:code.git` format for the endpoint, both of which will give you a permission denied error on push.